# Luna Eclipse shows a "semantic Error" on the same code that compiles correctly when using double C++/STL access...

Tags: c++, eclipse, stl, eclipse-luna

When accessing to the **swap** public member of a vector that is part of a deque, Eclipse Luna generates a semantic error.. (using external builder).

For example, using a C++ source somehow similar to this:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> vector_string;
typedef std::deque<vector_string> deque_vector_string;
...
deque_vector_string dvs;
vector_string vs;
...
vs.swap(dvs.front());
```

The semantic error comes for the swap public member. The code compiles/builds/runs as required...

The semantic error says:

```
Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: 
void swap(std::vector<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,std::allocator<std::basic_string<ch
 ar,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>> &) '
```

The code compiles, builds and runs under Linux, GCC 4.7.3
The code is build by an external make command tailored to my needs. (Not using eclipse internal builder)

Any hint why Eclipse gets confused?

Comment: Most likely a compiler bug, but looking at the error just before the one you shown would probably offer more of a clue. This looks like one message that's a part of the error that involves overload resolution. The signature for swap() looks right, the question is exactly what the compiler is thinking it's trying to do, at that point.

Comment: Sam, Agree with you that this may be a compiler issue..
From you answer I guess I may found a clue how to investigate: (Check what GCC version the external make files use and check which GCC Eclipse uses for its investigation)